# Confluence create page with custom image

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I want to create a page in confluence with custom information.

> API - (POST) confluence/rest/api/content

I am able to upload text and image successfully. If I use src for image that is uploaded somewhere,

```
e.g. www.example.com/myimage.png
```

then this image is successfully visible on my newly created page on confluence.

But, if I use src as data uri,

```
e.g. data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

then it does not display the image.

Please note that API does not throw any error but does not display the image as well.

**Working:**

```
{
    "type":"page",
    "title":"Document",
    "space":{"key":"DEMO"},
    "body":{
        "storage":{
            "value":"<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/64e1b8d34f425d19e1ee2ea7236d3028'/>",
            "representation":"storage"
        }
    }
}
```

**Not working:**

```
{
    "type":"page",
     "title":"Document",
     "space":{"key":"DEMO"},
     "body":{
         "storage":{
             "value":"<p>Hello</p><img height='284' width='750' src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'/><p>Hi</p>",
             "representation":"storage"
         }
     }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which Confluence version do you use? Is there any error-message? This is for JIRA, but maybe it also works Confluence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631361/add-attachment-to-jira-via-rest-api

Comment: @ppasler version of confluence is 5.9.9. 
No errors.
For adding attachments, image needs to be stored and image is dynamic in my case. That's why I cant use attachment API.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this if you use an HTML Macro.  See the "Storage format example" on this page: [HTML Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/html-macro-38273085.html).

You would just surround your html like this:

```
< ac:structured-macro ac:name = "html" >
    < ac:plain-text-body >
        <![CDATA[<div>HTML HERE</div>]]>
    </ ac:plain-text-body >
</ ac:structured-macro >
```

But you have to have the HTML Macro enabled.